# Why does a query in rails with a limit not work unless .all is put on the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

I have a query like this:

```
locations = Location.order('id ASC').limit(10)
```

which returns an array of 500 or so records - all the records in the table - i.e. the limit clause is being ignored.

Yet if I put a .all on the end:

```
locations = Location.order('id ASC').limit(10).all
```

it works and returns 10 records.

This code is being run in a rake task and I am using PostgreSQL if that makes any difference.

Why is it doing that? Surely the .all should not be required. What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder whether or not it's linked to the lazy loading: queries aren't triggered unless .all, .first ... are appended

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Because I am using 3.0.9 and I cannot reproduce this..

Comment: What version of Rails are you running? It works for me in Rails 3.0x. Have you tried appending ".to_sql" to the end to see what query it is running?

Comment: Adding to_sql to the first example produces the correct SQL:

  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10

but the second one fails because the .all makes in into an array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the behaviour depends on how you are handling the `locations` variable after setting it.  This is because `Location.order('id ASC').limit(10)` isn't querying records but is returning an object of type `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  The query will only occur once you call `all`, `first`, `each`, `map`, etc. on that object.

In my testing,

```
Location.order('id ASC').limit(10).map { |l| l.id }
```

returns an array of 10 ids as you would expect.  But

```
Location.order('id ASC').limit(10).count
```

returns the total number of locations in the database, because it executes the SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "locations" LIMIT 10
```

which returns the full count of location rows (the limit is on the number of rows returned, not the count itself).

So if you are treating the result of `Location.order('id ASC').limit(10)` as an array by iterating through it, you should get the same result as if you had added `all`.  If you are calling `count`, you will not.  Kind of unfortunate, as I think ideally they should behave the same and you shouldn't have to know that you are dealing with an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of an array.

Comment: OK so I think you have nailed it. I was checking the size of locations using 

  puts "#{locations.size} items to look up"

forgetting that locations is a Relation at that point not an array. 

So .size does seem to have different behaviour on a Relation and the array produced by a query on that Relation which is certainly not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is my explanation 
First of all if you do `Location.order('id ASC').limit(10).class` you'll see `ActiveRecord::Relation` next on the [site with rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) `ActiveRecord::Relation` doesn't have a method `all` however it includes `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods` and if you look there you'll find next

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 142
def all(*args)
  args.any? ? apply_finder_options(args.first).to_a : to_a
end
```

so it calls `to_a` method 
As was mentioned in the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough) this method is defined as

```
def to_a  
  ...
  @records = eager_loading? ? find_with_associations : @klass.find_by_sql(arel.to_sql)  
  ...  
  @records  
end
```

so it does SQL query on a third line with `@records = eager_loading? ? find_with_associations : @klass.find_by_sql(arel.to_sql)`